# how to save the elements value that is created with js direct| i want to use client side

Tags: javascript, html

i want to create a chat and i have been working on it.
here is the code below

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Aswin's Good Apps</title>
    <!-- add icon link -->
    <link rel = "icon" href = 
    "https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/AswinIcon.png"
            type = "image/x-icon">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <style>
    body{
    background-color:pink;
    color:purple;
     font: 15px Arial, sans-serif;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  body{
     width: 100%;
  }
}
.
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 5px 0 22px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: none;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Add a background color when the inputs get focus */
input[type=text]:focus, input[type=password]:focus {
  background-color: #ddd;
  outline: none;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

.cancelbtn {
  padding: 14px 20px;
  background-color: #8B0000;
}

.cancelbtn, .signupbtn {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.signupbtn{
background-color:#013220;

}


.container {
  padding: 20px;
}


.modal {
  display: none; 
  position: fixed; 
  z-index: 1; 
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
  overflow: auto; 
  background-color: #0000ffff;
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.modal-content {
  background-color: #ff8c00;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; 
}


hr {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
 

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 35px;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: purple;
  cursor: pointer;
}


.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

    a{
    font-size:25px;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:50px;
    }
    h2{
    font-size:50px;
    background-color: pink;
    }
    div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
 
  padding: 12px;
 
}
#loading {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
z-index: 1;
text-align: center;
color:green;
  background-color:yellow;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  left: calc(50% - 45px);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}
div.sticky1 {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
 
  padding: 12px;
 
}

#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
  margin: -76px 0 0 -76px;
  border: 16px solid greenyellow;
  border-radius: 60%;
  border-top: 16px solid yellow;
  border-radius:60%;
  border-bottom: 16px solid yellow;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;


}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom { 
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 } 
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}

#myDiv {
  display: none;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}
p{
    font-size: 25px;
}


    </style>
    
    </head>
    <body onload="myFunction()" style="margin:0;">
        <div id="body">
        <script>
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
  myVar = setTimeout(showPage, 3000);
  document.getElementById('fail').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('goonthetrack').style.display='none';//
    
    let messages = localStorage.getItem('message');
    console.log(messages);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = messages;
 
}   

function showPage() {
  document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("loading").style.display="none";
 

}
//this will filter the results to which they have searched far

function searchresult(){
    //this line tells the html tags we have used
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
  //this collects the inputs id
    input = document.getElementById("mysearch");
    //this tells about the filter
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
function validate()
{

    if(   document.getElementById("text1").value == "aswin.arulvel@gmail.com"
       && document.getElementById("text2").value == "aswinwebsitepass" )
    {
          document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Hello Aswin";
   document.getElementById('goonthetrack').style.display='block';
     document.getElementById("signup2").style.display = "none" ;
     document.getElementById("login1").style.display = "none" ;
      
    }
    else if(   document.getElementById("text1").value == "sathya.arulvel@gmail.com"
       && document.getElementById("text2").value == "sathyasaccount01" )
       {
          document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Hello Sathya!";
   document.getElementById('goonthetrack').style.display='block';
     document.getElementById("signup2").style.display = "none" ;
     document.getElementById("login1").style.display = "none" ;
      
    }
   
   else if(document.getElementById("text1").value == "arulvel.kumarasamy@gmail.com"
   &&  document.getElementById("text2").value == "skar$SP50zxcvArulaccount")
   {
     document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Hello Arulvel!";
   document.getElementById('goonthetrack').style.display='block';
     document.getElementById("signup2").style.display = "none" ;
     document.getElementById("login1").style.display = "none" ;
}

else if(document.getElementById("text1").value == "mine@3478"
   &&  document.getElementById("text2").value == "mine@3478")
   {
   document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = "Hello Shreyan!";
    document.getElementById('goonthetrack').style.display='block';
   document.getElementById("login1").style.display = "none" ;
   document.getElementById("signup2").style.display = "none" ;
}
else
    {
        alert( "validation failed" );
         document.getElementById("fail").style.display = "block" ;
    }
}



function addmessaage()
            {
               let li = document.createElement("li");
       let li2 = li.classname = "li2";
  let textToChange = document.getElementById('chatmessage').value;
  let t= document.createTextNode(textToChange);
 li.appendChild(t);
                
  document.getElementById('result').appendChild(li);
  document.getElementById('chatmessage').value ="";
  var multisave = document.getElementById('result').value;
  for (i = 0 ; i < li2.length; i++) {
    li2[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
     
    }
  }             
  
            localStorage.setItem("message", textToChange);
           
                
            }
    
            
           
</script>

<a href="goodapps.w3spaces.com/fractionscalc.html">We just put fraction calculer! Explore it!           
        <div class="container mt-3" style="background-color:pink; text-align:left;">
    <div class="sticky">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="nav-item">
          <p id="p1">Not logged in</p>
      </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" style="font-size:20px;">  <i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="login1" data-toggle="tab" href="#login" style="font-size:20px;"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i>Log In</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" id="signup2" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3" style="font-size:20px;"> <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>Sign Up</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" style="font-size:20px;"><i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i>Good Apps</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu4" style="font-size:20px;"><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i>Chat</a>
    </li>
    <iframe  style="text-align:right;"width="145" height="102" src="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/dateaswin.html" style="float:right; text-decoration: none; margin-right: 100px;">
     </iframe>
</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div style="background-color:pink;"class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
      <i class="fa fa-home" style="font-size:50px;"></i><h3><i class="fa-duotone fa-house"></i>HOME</h3>
     <img src="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/AswinIcon.png"/ width="200" height="360px">
      <p>Welcome to Aswin.</p>
     
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#login" style="font-size:20px;">Login</a>
     <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3" style="font-size:20px;"> Sign Up</a>
    </div>
    <div id="login" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <i class="fa fa-sign-in" style="font-size:50px;"> </i></i><h3>Login</h3>
      <p>Log in to save your work and have a more personalized experience.</p>
     <form action="#home">
     <input type="text" style = "width:15%;"class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="text1" />
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" id="text2" style="width:15%;"/>
    <input type="button" value="Login"  class="btn btn-info" onclick="javascript:validate()" />
    </form>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" id="fail">
        <p>Incorrect username or password.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-success" id="goonthetrack">
        <p>You have succesfuly logged in.</p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
      <h3>Good Apps</h3>
      <p>These are all good apps and have a lot of helpful info and all that stuff Items that are tagged "Under Development" are not finished and may have issues.</p>
        <input type="search" id="mysearch" placeholder="Search Apps..." style="margin-top: 8px;
     
          padding: 14px;
            float: right; " onkeyup="searchresult()"
            >
        <ul id="myUL">
        
            <li> <a href="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/intropage1tutorial.html">Aswin's Tutorials</a></li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li><a href="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/intropage1stories.html">Aswin's Stories</a></li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li><a href="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/aswin_sentences.html">Aswin's Sentences</a></li>
    <br>
    <br>
<li><a href="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/aswingames.html">Aswin's Games</a></li>
    <br>
    <br>
<li>    <a href="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/calculater.html">Aswin's Calculater</a></li>
    <br>
    <br>
    <li><a href="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/docs.html">Aswin's Writer</a></li> 

    <br>
    <br>
    <li><a href="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/code.html">Aswin's Code Editor</a></li>
    <br>
    <br>
<li>    <a href="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/dictonary.html">Aswin's Dictonary</a></li>
    <br>
    <br>
<li>    <a href="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/galaxydirectorintro.html"> Aswin's Galaxy Director (under devolopment)</a>
    </li><br>
    <br>
<li>    <a href="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/starcollage.html">Aswin's Star Collage(under devolopment)</a>
    </li><br>
    <br>
    
<li>    <a href="https://goodapps.w3spaces.com/facts.html">Aswin's Facts(under devolopment)</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
        <div id="menu3" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
              <i class="fa fa-user-plus" style="font-size:50px;" aria-hidden="true"></i><h3>Sign UP</h3>
          <form action="#home">
          <p>Enter your email:</p>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" required>
          <p>Set a password:</p>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" required>
          <p>Repeat Password:</p>
          <input type="password" class="form-control"  required>
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" required style="text-align:left;" name="I agree to the terms of service." id="agree" value="I agree to the terms of service."/><p>By signing up, I agree to the terms of service.</p>
 <input type="submit" class="form-control" value="Sign Up">
  </form>
  
  </div>
  <div id="menu4" class="container tab-pane fade"><br>
              <i class="fa fa-comment" style="font-size:50px;" aria-hidden="true"></i><h3>chat</h3>
          <form action="#home">
             
     <ul id="result" style="font-size:50px; display: inline-block;overflow:auto; height:150px;" class="form-control">
             
         </ul>
          <input type="text" id="chatmessage" class="form-control">
          <input type="button" value="Send" onclick="addmessaage()"  id="save" class="btn btn-success">
         
  </form>
  
  </div>
</div> 

        <div class="sticky">

            
        
         
    </iframe>
        
  


</div>
  
    

    
    </div>
        </div>
        <div id="loader"></div><p id="loading">Loading...</p>
        
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

i want to save the elements that the js has been created.
i want to use client-side javascript and use localstorage().
issue is i can't save multiple messages.
go to the chat section and make the snippet full screen
please help me

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? What exact is the issue you're facing with?

Comment: `i = -5;` what??? *elements*? What elements? Value? what value? Of the message? PS **never** use event listeners inside loops. Specially not the `onclick`. Read on MDN about addEventListener()

Comment: Also, stop using inline `style=""` attributes. CSS should be in the respective `<style>` tag or rather `<link>` to file.

Comment: Also, stop using inline `on*` handlers. JavaScript should be in one place only, ant that's the respective `<script>` tag or file.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, — if you want to use client side with `localStorage` what's the purpose of creating a Chat app? To chat with a *younger you*?

Comment: i edited my post to be more accurate and what i'm doing